# Some Rabbis today are able to trace their lineage back to Sinai, without omitting a single generation. Has any published a lineage that I can share?

Tags: family-members, shevatim-12-tribes, genealogy, har-sinai, bamidbar-numbers-book-of

The atheist claim is that there is no evidence for a [personal] god, of which the Jewish retort is the mass revelation at Mount Sinai. When I assert this fact, I am asked

- Where are their accounts recorded? [ Numbers ]
- What are their names? [ 13 tribes of Israel ]
- How are their accounts verified? [ Each Tribe was given a Torah to reproduce and maintain and to this day, we have a perfectly preserved written torah. Then it is a process of, "My father X said his father Y, who said his father Z, who said his father..." etc ]

I remember my favourite Rabbi, Rabbi Immanuel Schochet, claimed that he was able to trace his lineage back to David, and subsequently back to Mt Sinai, without missing a single generation, and that I have heard more than once that many others are able to do similar. I have never actually been able to see any of these lineages done to completion, and I am unable to find anything on google.

I would actually like to be able to see one of these done to completion, with all the reasoning requisite.

For example, I heard that if you can trace your lineage back to Rashi, that he had [ Until it was destroyed ] a comprehensive lineage going back to [ I forget. ]

Anyways. Does anything like this actually exist? Ideally with each generation and each date next to their name? Could we compile a sample lineage if one does not exist?

Thanks.

Comment: My Heritage is a popular site that people use to trace their family tree.

Comment: This question seems - to me - to be pasting together two completely unrelated issues.

Comment: There is a group of people that used to be online descended from King David. There is also one gentleman of Sephardi lineage who claims to have the senior lineage claim. But these websites no longer appear active. Personally, I worked on translating a person family document for a man in San Francisco that did exactly what you are describing. They are called “Sefer or Megillat Yuchasin”. You can also find a detailed description of this in the Responsa of Machane Ephraim. He possessed such a document.